How can I make a point in the middle of a face?
I'm making a moth creature, and trying to model its fur. I'm trying to make a box with loop cuts and a point in the middle of one of the faces. I watched multiple tutorials on how to make the points, but none of them show how to make one in the middle of a face. It always ends up with the point not being connected to the object, or it's not where it's supposed to be. I'm new to Blender. Does anyone know how to do this?

Select a face a got to Face > Poke Faces

Or you can select the face and press I to inset it, then S to scale and 0 to scale all the inside vertices to the same spot. Then merge them by pressing M > Merge by Distance.
You can also use the Knife tool with K to just cut across a face a couple times to make a vertex in the middle
I don't know what you are trying to do exactly but I can't really think of a way to make fur by starting here. Poking a faces is not a tool that is used that much. You are turning quads into triangles so you better have a good reason for making the geometry more complicated like that.
